# add new user to wordpress with REST API in flutter

Tags: json, wordpress, flutter, dart

I'm creating a flutter app for my WordPress website.
I use REST PI to do this.
My problem is that I want to have a login/register page at first of my app , that users can register or login with , to wordpress website.
I don't know how I can create new user with REST API in wordpress.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/) yet? That's where I'd start.

Comment: Yes
I have read the documentation.
But I do not know which JSON code to authenticate.
In principle, I did not understand the authentication page.

Answer (score -1):

[WP Rest User](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-user/) plugin allows you to register and forgot password user without you needing to send administrator credentials.

You can use [JWT Authentication for WP REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/) or [Basic Auth](https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth) plugin to authenticate the user.

Comment: The  plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-user/ is closed at the moment :(

Comment: wordpress have it own rest api and that can be used with any client to communicate ... no need to add third party plugin which are outdated.